# Make GeoJSON easily editable

Tags: leaflet, geojson, qgis2web

I have a map (using Leaflet) that uses GeoJSON files as source. These are formatted to fit in Leaflet.

How can I make the GeoJSON files easily editable so that an authorized person with no Leaflet/JavaScript- knowledge can add new points or edit properties of existing points?

Comment: Files are static, if you want to add/delete/updated data you need a database online. The use something like PHP (Java, Node, Etc) to serve the data in a GeoJSON format, that you would use instead of a file. You would use AJAX requests to pass the data back to the server.

Comment: Ok I hoped there might be an option without getting in touch with database. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The data and HTML file are on the server, your page displays in a browser on the client. You would need to write back to the server to update the data. Because of the security risk, not many server admins would let you do file changes on a server from a web page.

Comment: And how would authorized person be able to change the content of the database?

Comment: Put the html edit page behind a log in or use a log in to enable the save button.